# Hibernate ternary relationship and additional table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 3 entities that can have a relationship with each other. So a good step to solve this problem is to use another table to store the 3 ID's of the 3 entities.
Lets say the entities are X, Y and Z.

```
@Entity
public class XYZ {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "X_ID")
    private X x;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Y_ID")
    private Y y ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Z_ID")
    private Z z;

    public XYZ(){

    }


}
```

Entities X, Y and Z have their own attributes and own Primary Key.
I have a couple of questions.

1) Should i add @OneToMany to the X, Y and Z entities on the attribute private XYZ xyz; ? Or is it not necessary when we only want to find the relationship with the help of the XYZ table.

2) In the entity XZY i have normal getters and setters for the entities X, Y and Z. I'm giving the whole entity. Is Hibernate automatically going to pic the Primary Keys of X, Y and Z in XYZ entity?

Last question
3) Let's say I delete object X that is being used in the XYZ entity, is hibernate automatically going to remove the record in XYZ entity? Or do I have to add additional info.

Sorry for these questions, but Hibernate is very new for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Speciying @OneToMany on the other side (on X, Y and Z entities) is
   not necessary, unless you want to make your relationship
   bi-directional.
2. You already have defined the @JoinColumn annotations:
   X_ID, Y_ID, Z_ID which are the foreign key columns taken from the
   primary keys of your X, Y and Z entities, respectively.
3. If you want to perform a cascade remove, in such a way that when you delete X the child entity XYZ is also deleted, then this is the time when you need to make your relationship bi-directional. You need to specify a @OneToMany mapping on your X entity and add a cascade attribute.

Example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="x", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
Set<XYZ> xyzSet;
```